# Cannot Add control to form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to add a Usercontrol to a form.  The UserControl is in a separate project than the form, but is in the same solution. I have added this control to other forms in the past, however, something has changed and I get the following error:

> "Failed to create the component `MessageDisplayListControl`. 
>   The error message follows: 
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type AceXtremeNET.Utilities.Message' in Assymbly AceXtremeNET, Version=10.0.0.273,...... is not marked as serializable. at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMember(RuntimeType type) at ...."

The control does get added to the `.Designer.cs`, however, it is not displayed in the visual GUI.  Everytime I try to build, I get multiple errors that give the same basic error as above, that the 'AceXtremeNET.Utilities.Message' is not Serializable.

**--------- Edit ------------------**

My control has the following property which appears to the problem.

```
public IList<Message> MessageList {get{return _getList();} {set {_lostList(value);}}
```

No code in the control is dependant on this property as it was meant purley as a get/set accessor.
Whenever I comment out the code, Everything appears to work correctly.  Otherwise I can the error I mentioned above.  I have receieved another error on build as I mentioned before, and it appears this is the only Property that is trying to be Serialized.

**--------- Edit (Stack Trace)------------------**

```
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialzation.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Type objectType, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, SerializationBinder binder)
at System.Runtime.SerializationFormatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
...
```

**--------- Edit (Control Properties)------------------**

```
public MessageControl MessageDisplay {get{return messageControl1;}} // This is another user control I created.  I've not had any problems with this control.
public MessageListBox {get { return listBox1; } }
public int MessageCount { get { return MessageListBox.Items.Count; }}
public bool ValidSelection { get { return (SelectedIndex >= 0 && SelectedIndex < MessageCount); } }
public Message SelectedMessage { get { return listBox1.SelectedItem as Message; } set { MessageDisplay.Message = Value; } }
public int SelectedIndex { get { return listBox1.SelectedIndex; } set { listBox1.SelectedIndex = value; } }
```

Comment: Did you update to new version of the AceXtremeNET control?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Scott:  I have.  The AceXtremeNET Control is actually my own project and is a part of the VS Solution.  It is the first build target of the solution.

Comment: @svick: I don't have the complete stack trace as VS wont display it.  The error occurs not at RunTime but at Design Time (or build time when I try to build).  I'll add the incomplete stack trace in the original post.

Comment: Can you try just adding [Serializable] attribute to your Message class and see what happens?  Did you add any new types to that class that may not be serializable?

Comment: For now I will remove the property and make the getList() and loadList(Message) functions public for getter/setter.  This shouldn't break anything since I have not yet released the control.

Comment: @Scott: I am not using anything designated as [Serializable] in the AceXtremeNET project, so it was a surprise to see this error.  No where do I try myself to serialize anything.  I will try adding the attribute and see what happens.  I'll post the results.

Comment: @Scott: That does appear to let it work.  Now the question is Why must it be serializable?  One not I did not mention before, is that I just recently made the Message class ICloneable. I'm not sure why that would cause this error though.

Comment: could you please put list of control class properties here?

Comment: I added the list of properties to the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

read about [DesignerSerializationVisibility Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility.aspx)

put this attribute  on MessageList property

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

in this situation designer will lost user change in MessageList 
but if you set it to

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```

Designer will save the Property Content in Designer.cs of control host

Comment: Thanks! I'll look over the information you provided and post tomorrow with my findings.  Also I added the list of properties that my control has.