# C# UserControl Issue: Invalid Resx File

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a costom user control that I have created.  I want to add another button to the user control however, whenever I make any Design time changes to the GUI I receieve the following error on build.

> Invalid Resx file. Could not load type type
>   AceXtremeNET.Utilities.Message, AceXtremeNET, Ver ...., Ensure that
>   the necessary references have been added to your project.

This error occurs with basically any edit of the control at Design Time.  The control does render properly in the Designer as well as debug properly when I run the debugger.

Example:

1. I add a button to the control and build.  I receieve the above error.
2. Delete the added button and build. I still receieve the above error.
3. Revert my code (using subversion) to a version before adding the button, and everything builds/debugs ok.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Try closing all forms, controls, designers etc. Clean Solution, and then rebuild. I have had similar problems to this when designing UserControl before.. It worked for me, YMMV

Comment: @Otiel: Actually it was a pretty good observation.  Just for kicks, I tried the solution from my other question and even though they were completely different errors.  I don't seem to be having the issues anymore.  Thanks Otiel :)

Comment: Even though the errors were different.  As Otiel had pointed out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158419/cannot-add-control-to-form
Provides the solution.  It appears the Designer has issues when using objects that don't support Serialization as Properties.  Checkout the above question for the solution.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out in the end :). You can answer your own question and accept the answer. That will help others that encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution can be found in the following stackoverflow article

[Cannot Add control to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158419/cannot-add-control-to-form)