# Invalid Resx while using collection in usercontrol

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I created a usercontrol in vb.net winforms that has a Dictionary as property. I am getting the following error message:

> Error 1   Invalid Resx file. Could not load type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[MIDAS.CheckedComboBoxItem, MIDAS,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   which is used in the .RESX file.  Ensure that the necessary references
>   have been added to your project. Line 135, position
>   5.    C:\Users\desig.nizam\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MIDAS\MIDAS\FGEO\FGEO.resx   135 5   MIDAS

I am using this control in some forms successfully, but not in the new ones. If I delete the controls of the forms I can compile without error.

I googled a solution and could find a lot of related topic, but none of them helped me to solve my case.

Comment: it sounds like a designer serialization issue.  what is in the dictionary and can you show the code exposing it as a property.. why a dictionary vs a collection as a property?

Comment: That is exactly this. The topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158419/cannot-add-control-to-form showed me the solution for this problem.

Comment: you will have to change the Dictionary to a NET Collection - NOT the VB collection - then work on serializing whatever goes into the collection mostly the Attributes mentioned in the link, but also possibly a TypeConverter.  The issue is that VS cant serialize it, so it is storing info in the RESX file (probably Base64) but cannot deserialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to set this attribute to Dictionary:

```
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
```

The same problem was already discussed in

[Cannot Add control to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158419/cannot-add-control-to-form)